# Vuex $Store is in Typescript undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, store, vuex

I'm trying to use Vuex 3.0.1 and Vue 2.6.6 in my project with typescript.

store.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        selectedComponent:'appParent'
    }
});
```

main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {store} from './store/store';

import App from './AppWP.vue';

public render(): void {
    const id: string = `wp-${this.instanceId}`;
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `<div id="${id}"></div>`;

    let el = new Vue({
      el: `#${id}`,
      store,
      render: h => h(App)

    });
}
```

Player.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-3">
      <div class="card alert alert-success" style="width:170px">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button @click="selectComp">{{player.firstName}} {{player.lastName}}</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["player"],
  methods: {
    selectComp(){
      this.$store.selectedComponent='appPlayerInfo';
    }
  },

};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

my problem:

> $store is undefined

I have looked at a lot of questions already trying to solve this but no success!

Comment: A quick note, you would access the store property `selectedComponent` as `this.$store.state.selectedComponent` as it's stored in the `state` property of the `$store`, not directly on `$store`. Also you would modify `selectedComponent` and other store properties via actions and mutations, not by directly mutating it on `this.$store.state`.

Comment: As you said I have changed selectedComponent but stil this.$store.state is undefined.

Comment: I'm trying to do same, also in SpFx, did you ever have any success with this?